# Mat-chips display 5 on a row

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have a list of mat-chips and I'm trying to display them over multiples rows. I want to have 5 chips on a row and chip's size to don't increase (have a standard value, for example 100px). If there was one element on the row, it would take the whole width which I don't want. I tried with flex basis, but it's doesn't work. How can I do it?

HTML:

```
    <div class="chip" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start">
        <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite Fruits</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" id="chip-item" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <button matChipRemove>
        <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.chip {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#chip-item {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

Comment: Please create a stack blitz.

Comment: add chip class on <mat-chip> selector where you used ngFor directive. Remove it from the top div.